# how to find checkbox control in kendo ui gird in angular2

Tags: angular

In **Angular2** application implementing multiple selection in kendo Grid,Is there any way to find checkbox control in kendo Grid

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete. verifiable and reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

To improve your chances of getting an answer [it is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that you provide a detailed description of your problem.

Anyway, I found this [example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Selection/grid-selection-checkbox) of using checkboxes in Kendo Grids which might help you.